# c# certain timer sequence

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to do a sequence of timed events for a morse code blinking light. The programm should be able to be worked with while the light is blinking.

So there will be a Long pause at the beginning and then it will start to blink long and short signs with small pauses in between and then start over again.

Example Sequence

- Light off 3000ms
- Light on  1200ms
- Light off  500ms
- Light on   400ms
- Light off  500ms
- Light on  1200ms
- Light off  500ms
- Light on   400ms
- start over again

I tried this code but it only freezes the programm

```
private void Morse()
{
    System.Timers.Timer MorseCode = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);
    MorseCode.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(long);
    MorseCode.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(short);
    MorseCode.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(long);
    MorseCode.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(short);

    void short(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        MorseCode.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ColorChange);
        MorseCode.Interval = 400;
        MorseCode.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ColorChange);
        MorseCode.Interval = 500;
    }
    void long(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        MorseCode.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ColorChange);
        MorseCode.Interval = 1200;
        MorseCode.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ColorChange);
        MorseCode.Interval = 500;
    }
    void ColorChange(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(BlinkLight.BackColor == Color.Gray)
        {
            BlinkLight.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
        }
        else
        {
            BlinkLight.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        }
    }    
}
```

So how do i make a sequence with different timings for a blinking light?

Comment: In WinForms apps use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, because it guarantees to run event handler code on UI thread - you can create it through designer. Also, I would recommend using one timer to handle all this logic with small interval like 100, instead of having 8 timers.

Comment: Thank you for your reccomendation i will try it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Task Parallel Library for this, this is included in .NET 4 and up. This will produce neat readable code like this:

```
private void Morse()
{
    BlinkShort().ContinueWith(          //
        BlinkShort).ContinueWith(       //  S
        BlinkShort).ContinueWith(       //
        BlinkLong).ContinueWith(        //
        BlinkLong).ContinueWith(        //  O
        BlinkLong).ContinueWith(        // 
        BlinkShort).ContinueWith(       //
        BlinkShort).ContinueWith(       //  S
        BlinkShort);                    // 
}
```

Example implementation of helper methods:

```
private Task BlinkShort(Task previousTask = null)
{
    var action = new Action(() =>
    {
        SetColorSafe(true);
        Task.Delay(400).Wait();
        SetColorSafe(false);
        Task.Delay(500).Wait();
    });
    var t = Task.Run(action);
    if (previousTask != null) // already threaded
    {
        t.Wait();
    }

    return t;
}
private Task BlinkLong(Task previousTask = null)
{
    var action = new Action(() =>
    {
        SetColorSafe(true);
        Task.Delay(1200).Wait();
        SetColorSafe(false);
        Task.Delay(500).Wait();
    });
    var t = Task.Run(action);
    if (previousTask != null) // already threaded
    {
        t.Wait();
    }

    return t;
}

private void SetColorSafe(bool on)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() => {
            SetColorSafe(on);
        }));
        return;
    }
    if (on)
    {
        BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
    }
    else
    {
        BackColor = Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this - NuGet "System.Reactive.Windows.Forms".

Then you can do this:

```
int[] timings = new [] { 3000, 1200, 500, 400, 500, 1200, 500, 400 };

IObservable<System.Drawing.Color> sequence =
    Observable
        .Generate(
            0,
            x => x < timings.Length,
            x => x + 1,
            x => x % 2 == 1 ? System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue : System.Drawing.Color.Gray,
            x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timings[x]));

IDisposable subscription =
    sequence
        .Repeat()
        .ObserveOn(BlinkLight)
        .Subscribe(color => BlinkLight.BackColor = color);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [Enigmativity's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53391685/7444103). If you know `System.Reactive`, that's a goog choice.

This a simple solution using a asyncronous Task.
I'm passing to the async method:
- a `List<Tuple<int, int>>` that represents the spaces and durations of the signals
- a `Control` refrence that will serve as the visual output
- a `CancellationToken`, used to signal when the Task should be terminated.

The Task can be cancelled, then start over again with the same sequence or a new one.
If not cancelled, the Task will go on indefinitely, *playing* the current sequence.
Here, I'm using a Button to start the Task. I could be anything else.

Note that I've modified the sequence and the timings a little. The pause between each sequence iteration is at the end of the sequence, so it starts the signal immediately, then it pauses it after each sequence is executed.

When a cancellation request is issued, the Task will complete the sequence before cancelling:
`if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;` is checked only after a sequence is completed, to avoid messing with the timings. But this could be modified to check for cancellation after each long pause.

```
CancellationTokenSource source;
CancellationToken token;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (source != null)
    {
        source.Cancel();
        source.Dispose();
        source = null;
        return;
    }

    source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    token = source.Token;
    List<Tuple<int, int>> MorseCodeSequence = new List<Tuple<int, int>>()
    {
        new Tuple<int, int>(1200, 200),
        new Tuple<int, int>(400, 200),
        new Tuple<int, int>(1200, 200),
        new Tuple<int, int>(400, 2000)
    };

    Task.Run(()=> MorseSequence(MorseCodeSequence, this.btnMorse, token));
}

public async Task MorseSequence(List<Tuple<int, int>> MorseSequence, Control MorseCodeOutputObject, CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (Tuple<int, int> MorseTiming in MorseSequence)
        {
            MorseCodeOutputObject.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                { MorseCodeOutputObject.BackColor = Color.Cyan; }));
            await Task.Delay(MorseTiming.Item1);
            MorseCodeOutputObject.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                { MorseCodeOutputObject.BackColor = Color.Gray; }));
            await Task.Delay(MorseTiming.Item2);
        }
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
    };
}
```

The `SOS` sequence

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> SOSMorseSequence = new List<Tuple<int, int>>()
{
    new Tuple<int, int>(400, 200),
    new Tuple<int, int>(400, 200),
    new Tuple<int, int>(400, 300),
    new Tuple<int, int>(1200, 200),
    new Tuple<int, int>(1200, 200),
    new Tuple<int, int>(1200, 300),
    new Tuple<int, int>(400, 200),
    new Tuple<int, int>(400, 200),
    new Tuple<int, int>(400, 2000),
};
```